# How to skip preceding rows before the header row in MongoDB import of a TSV file?

Tags: mongodb, import

In a TSV file, I have varying rows that precede the actual header row.
Depending on the type of data collection the number of preceding rows.
data looks like the text blob below.

I need to be able to start the import beginning with a specific row number or ideally where the headers appear in MongoDB using compass if possible.

```
Peak Name: OZopiclone
Internal Standard: Zolpidem D-6
Q1/Q3 Masses: 389.10/244.80 Da

Fit Quadratic   Weighting   1 / x   Iterate No
a0  0.00109
a1  0.0121
a2  -1.53e-006
Correlation coefficient 0.9998
Use Area



Sample Name Sample ID   Analyte Peak Name   Sample Type Sample Comment  Set Number  Acquisition Method  Rack Type   Rack Position   Vial Position   Plate Type  Plate Position  Analyte Concentration (ng/mL)   Calculated Concentration (ng/mL)    Accuracy (%)    Weight To Volume Ratio  Sample Annotation   Disposition Analyte Units   Analyte Peak Area for DAD (mAU x min)   Analyte Peak Height (cps)   Analyte Peak Height for DAD (mAU)   Analyte Expected RT (min)   Analyte RT Window (sec) Analyte Centroid Location (min) Analyte Start Scan  Analyte Start Time (min)    Analyte Stop Scan   Analyte Stop Time (min) Analyte Integration Type    Analyte Signal To Noise Analyte Peak Width (min)    Standard Query Status   Analyte Mass Ranges (Da)    Analyte Wavelength Ranges (nm)  Height Ratio    Analyte Annotation  Analyte Channel Analyte Peak Width at 50% Height (min)  Analyte Slope of Baseline (%/min)   Analyte Processing Alg. Analyte Peak Asymmetry  IS Peak Name    IS Units    IS Peak Area for DAD (mAU x min)    IS Peak Height (cps)    IS Peak Height for DAD (mAU)    IS Concentration (ng/mL)    IS RT Window (sec)  IS Centroid Location (min)  IS Start Scan   IS Start Time (min) IS Stop Scan    IS Stop Time (min)  IS Integration Type IS Signal To Noise  IS Peak Width (min) IS Mass Ranges (Da) IS Wavelength Ranges (nm)   IS Channel  IS Peak Width at 50% Height (min)   IS Slope of Baseline (%/min)    IS Processing Alg.  IS Peak Asymmetry   Use Record  Record Modified Calculated Concentration for DAD (ng/mL)    Relative Retention Time Dilution Factor Analyte Peak Area (counts)  IS Peak Area (counts)   Area Ratio  Analyte Retention Time (min)    IS Retention Time (min) IS Expected RT (min)    File Name   Acquisition Date    Response Factor Analyte Integration Quality IS Integration Quality  
WATER       O6 MAM  Unknown     0   190128 OF Panel 63 PRO1.dam MTP 96 Standard 1   1   MTP 96 Standard 1   N/A No Peak N/A 0.00            ng/mL   N/A 0.00    N/A 2.54    30.0    0.00    0   0.00    0   0.00    No Peak N/A 0.00    N/A 328.200/165.200 Da  N/A 0.00e+000       N/A 0.00    0.00e+000   Specify Parameters - MQIII  0.00    Tapentadol D-3  ng/mL   N/A 9.18e+002   N/A 1.00    30.0    3.31    55  3.25    67  3.38    Base To Base    N/A 0.132   225.100/107.000 Da  N/A N/A 8.78e-002   -5.51e+001  Specify Parameters - MQIII  3.66        0   N/A 0.000   1.00    0.00    3210.   0.00    0.0 3.28    3.22    211005 MS1 P63 OF JP 699613-700684.wiff 10/5/2021 7:08:49 PM    N/A 0.00    0.391   
WATER       O7-Aminoclonazepam  Unknown     0   190128 OF Panel 63 PRO1.dam MTP 96 Standard 1   1   MTP 96 Standard 1   N/A No Peak N/A 0.00            ng/mL   N/A 0.00    N/A 3.00    30.0    0.00    0   0.00    0   0.00    No Peak N/A 0.00    N/A 286.100/121.000 Da  N/A 0.00e+000       N/A 0.00    0.00e+000   Specify Parameters - MQIII  0.00    7-Aminoclonazepam d-4 2 ng/mL   N/A 7.40e+002   N/A 1.00    30.0    2.95    27  2.88    36  3.00    Base To Base    N/A 0.115   290.100/121.100 Da  N/A N/A 4.33e-002   0.00e+000   Specify Parameters - MQIII  0.517       0   N/A 0.000   1.00    0.00    2070.   0.00    0.0 2.96    3.03    211005 MS1 P63 OF JP 699613-700684.wiff 10/5/2021 7:08:49 PM    N/A 0.00    0.937
```

Comment: Why not just strip the unwanted leading lines and then proceed?

Comment: I will have a ton of data files every day and opening all of them up in excel and deleting them is time-consuming when you have several hundred. I can do this in SQL but am trying to move to Mongo as it doesn't have to update the schema every time I get new information.

Comment: To strip the leading lines, could you do something like `awk -F "\t" '{a[++i,0]=$0;a[i,1]=NF}END{nf=NF;for(j=1;j<=i;j++)if(a[j,1]==nf){print a[j,0]}}' example-wHeader.tsv > example-woHeader.tsv`?

Comment: If you have tons/hundreds of data files, I'd suggest using [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/ "Link to mongoimport docs -->") rather than `compass` to import your data.  The entire process could be automated.